# How to add social buttons like facebook and twitter in the footer of a theme?

Tags: menus, widgets, facebook

Hi I own the blog camilamfotografia.com.br
and I'd like to add social buttons in the footer or in the navigation menu to link my site to facebook twitter flickr pinterest etc...

I have tried without any success, can anyone help me please?

Thanks 
Camila

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Camilia, this is super easy to do with existing plugins, which you can find here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=social+media

But if you're keen to the coding yourself, and you have widgets in place, you could simply use the text widget that also allows for html and manually add your social media links something like:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/YourUsername">Twitter</a><a href="http://facebook.com/YourPage">Facebook</a>
```

If you don't have widgets in place, you simply need to access your templates footer in your directory. The path is usually something like: /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/footer.php